# DDD - Handling temporary inconsistency when handling domain events

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, eventual-consistency, event-handling

I realize that DDD advocates **eventual consistency**, thus allowing for a certain period of time in which the system might be inconsistent. Embracing eventual consistency, we can therefore model our aggregates in such a way that only 1 is updated per transaction.

However, my question is, what if the relationship between multiple aggregates is such that eventual consistency is either not acceptable, or compensating actions would be too complex to implement? Does that mean that DDD is not the right choice in that scenario, or does it mean that we simply cannot use the 1 aggregate per transaction rule? Or does this maybe mean that the multiple aggregates need to be merged into 1 greater aggregate?

To give a more concrete example, consider the following:
An auction system, composed of Items, Auctions, Bids, Users and UserBalance. Users can place a bid on an auction if the following conditions are met:

- They outbid the current highest bid, if any
- Their balance has enough funds to place the bid

When a bid is outbid, the user that placed the bid should receive the funds used in placing that bid. Users can increase their UserBalance by other actions, such as purchasing, rewards, etc.

I envisioned the following aggregates: Auction composed of Bids, User and UserBalance.

Imagine Auction has a method called `placeBid` that handles the bid placement logic.

In order to preserve the 1 aggregate per transaction rule, Auction should accept a userBalance object, and check if the bid placement is valid. If yes, it then proceeds to create a bid, commit the transaction and publish a domain event.
However, it can happen that a UserBalance no longer has sufficient funds to pay for a bid by the time the BidPlacedHandler is triggered. This means that other users would see the newly placed bid before the balance is updated. And this also means that once the UserBalance update fails, the current highest bid will need to be deleted, and the previous bid reinstated as the highest bid, unless of course another bid was placed in the meantime.

While handling these compensatory cases might be slightly unreadable, or difficult to grasp, my bigger concern is the fact that users might be able to see an invalid bid as the highest bid for an auction. Is there any guidelines as to how this problem would be approached, in this particular case, or in general?

Comment: Do you have a citation for the claim that "DDD advocates eventual consistency?"

Comment: `I envisioned the following aggregates: Auction composed of Bids, User and UserBalance.` -- None of those things are aggregates, except possibly Auctions.  A User is an entity.  A User Balance is a property of an account.

Comment: `users might be able to see an invalid bid as the highest bid for an auction.` -- Aren't bids essentially "not valid" until they are accepted?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I believe the following:
`Any rule that spans AGGREGATES will not be expected to be up-to-date at all times. Through event processing, batch processing, or other update mechanisms, other dependencies can be resolved within some specific time. [Evans, p. 128]`


See also [this post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=5)

Comment: OK, fair enough.  So now you need to craft your aggregates in such a way that aggregates can pass messages between each other without relying on inter-aggregate transactions.  That ought to be solvable by working out the inter-dependencies of your aggregates and adjusting your aggregate boundaries accordingly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In order to avoid unnecessary complexity, I omitted parts of the domain. UserBalance can contain multiple Entries, or be composed of events regarding paying/receiving funds if going with an EventSourced solution, therefore I classified it as an aggregate. Whether you call it Account or UserBalance is a matter of semantics, and i admit naming it account would have been more suitable in this case

Comment: How would your dilemma be solved in real-life?  If an auction house accepted a bid, but later found out that the bidder had insufficient funds, how would that be worked out?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that creating a bid in an Auction object needs to create an Entry in UserBalance/Account. This doesn't necessarily needs to be done in the same transaction, although I am wondering what the consequences of it might be

Comment: @RobertHarvey I imagine that a real-life auction would not care about the state of a user's Account, since, at the end of the auction, if the winner cannot pay, the item would go to the next highest bidder, because in a real-life auction, a user does not "pay" for every intermediate bid he places

Comment: OK, so now you have a model for how it might work in your aggregates.  You can do that, or you can bend the DDD rules a little bit and spend a few hundred milliseconds interrogating the account aggregate to see if the funds are available.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't necessarily need to interrogate the account aggregate during the creation of the bid. My bigger concern was "submitting" a bid before it is paid, and having other potential bidders see this bid as valid for a time being.

Comment: Why are you worried about that?  If the highest bidder cannot pay, the item goes to the next bidder, just as you said.

Comment: Here's my point.  Regardless of what Eric Evans, Martin Fowler or  Vaughn Vernon says, ultimately the behavior of the system is going to be governed by the *business rules at hand,* not necessarily by some notion of "eventual consistency" or any other software maxims. Vaughn Vernon doesn't have to deal with auction dead-beats; the auction house does.  Your job is to arrange your aggregates in such a way that you minimize immediate consistency across aggregates if you can, while still adhering to the auction house's business rules.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well in my particular case, I cannot model the Auction in such a way, because the project I am working on does not want the real-life version of an Auction, for various reasons, meaning a user must be able to pay for every bid that he places. 
I do agree with you that, in the end, business rules at hand will have the final say in the design, and that software maxims serve more as a guideline than a law. I was interested to see how other people solved this problem, and if maybe immediate consistency has some downsides that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: What downsides of immediate consistency are you familiar with?  When you stated that "DDD advocates eventual consistency," the first thing I thought of was *microservices.*  Microservices are the latest fad but, like the NoSQL wave before it, it comes with tradeoffs.  If you're building a monolith; it's a non-issue; everything is *immediately consistent.*  Microservices are supposed to work independently, which is why they are considered "eventually-consistent," and why hooking them up to a common database is considered a "bad practice." (scare quotes are intentional here).

Comment: Well immediate consistency for high traffic apps has the potential for multiple failed concurrent requests. Another "issue" is that if i want immediate consistency, i will need to have both aggregates in the same database, or rather on the same host.

Comment: I agree.  Is this particular app expected to be high-traffic?  (and by high-traffic, I mean *a lot* of traffic, on the order of Twitter or Facebook, or even Stack Overflow.)  Note that Stack Overflow is a *monolith.*  It doesn't use microservices or eventual consistency.

Comment: No, that kind of traffic is not expected from this app.

Comment: I conclude that you don't need the scalability that microservices and eventual consistency provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to begin this by first addressing the problem space here as I see a bit of misunderstanding regarding both "eventual consistency" and DDD.

DDD is a *design* process that understands real-world problems can sometimes reach a level of complexity that they cannot be cleanly separated and modeled into completely independent units. That is, *process* itself can have rules and when such a situation arises, eventual consistency *can be* employed to offer a solution. I don't read the quote you offer from the blue book (in the OP comments) as advocating for any mode of consistency, rather pointing out that eventual consistency is often a desirable and sometimes necessary attribute within a system of which we need to be aware when forming our expectations.

Whether or not a given system needs to employ an eventual consistent paradigm should be determined through analysis of its requirements in terms of scaling, not through analysis of it's design (though the former can *certainly* inform the latter). This decision should not be made lightly (and doesn't have to be all-or-nothing), because the trade-offs are steep and often require *much* greater complexity in terms of implementation where employed.

As to your system, I think you may have complected a couple of things together.

The first is that an `Auction` would be better understood/implemented as a `Saga`/`ProcessManger` rather than an `Aggregate`. That is, an `Auction` represents a grouping of related events that must be managed in terms of process. In this way, your `Auction` is given the responsibility to oversee *it's own* consistency and can therefore usefully abstract business requirements.

This flows into the second issue of not separating responsibilities into the correct entities. The issue you describe is predicated on your `Auction` needing to "ask" for an account balance. Clearly, it should be the responsibility of your `Account` (`UserBalance` is a confusing name) to keep track of the current balance. Therefore, it must also be responsible for creating a new `Bid`. In this way, we can cleanly separate the logic necessary for verifying an account balance from that of placing bids. Nobody at an auction cares about account balances, so let's keep that separate from our auction. Think of it like this, "how does an auction work?". It can be modeled relatively simply:

**OfferBidHandler** (moves money into escrow, creates `Bid`):

```
// throws NotFound
account = accounts.Find( cmd.UserId ) 

// throws InsuficientFunds or raises `BidOffered`
account.OfferBid( cmd.AuctionId, cmd.LotNumber, cmd.Amount )
```

**PlaceBidHandler** (keeps track of all `Bids` or maybe just highest `Bid`):

```
// throws NotFound
auctioneer = auctioneers.Find( cmd.AuctionId ) 

// raises Outbidded
auctioneer.ReceiveCompetingBid( cmd.UserId, cmd.LotNumber, cmd.Amount )
```

**RevokeBidHandler** (removes money from escrow):

```
// throws NotFound
account = accounts.Find( cmd.UserId ) 

account.RevokeBid( cmd.AuctionId, cmd.LotNumber )
```

The `Auction` (which *mediates* the process) is simply responsible for reacting to `BidOffered` events in a way to trigger `PlaceBid` **OR** `RevokeBid` commands (should `NotFound` be thrown), and reacting to `Outbidded` events in a way to trigger `RevokeBid` commands.

If you would like to keep `Account` and `Auction` in separate contexts (you don't want `Account.OfferBid`), this can be modified further to add an extra layer along the lines of: `PlaceOrder -> PaymentReceived -> PlaceBid` (in this case ordering a `Bid` and debiting account) and `BidRevoked -> RefundPayment` to cleanly separate accounts from auctions.